# iTunes on Windows 7 loses connection to other iTunes or Apple TV 2

Tags: itunes, windows, appletv, home-sharing

I can start iTunes on my Windows 7 desktop, and can browse it from my Apple TV 2. It works fine for a while, then randomly in the middle of the movie I'm watching it completely loses the connection and kicks me back to the Apple TV home screen. I have to restart iTunes to get it to work again.

This does not happen streaming from my MacBook Pro.

This also happens when Home Sharing between my MacBook and the desktop. I go to browse the desktop in iTunes to transfer something, it spins for a minute, then disconnects. Once again, a restart of iTunes on the desktop is required to get iTunes on my MacBook to see the desktop library again.

I've tried disabling the Windows Firewall to no avail.

Both iTunes and the Apple TV are up to date.

The network is solid with gigabit and a Linksys/Cisco E4200 with latest firmware. I had to disable WMM support to make AirPlay work.

Comment: Do you get any visible error?

Comment: Wired or wireless? Fixed or dynamic ip?

Comment: How is power management set in your Windows 7 desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Your iTunes Library file might have been corrupted, a more frequent problem with the last iTunes update, especially if your computer turns off, on or restarts frequently (more then once a day).

Your exact problem happened to me 1, maybe 2 weeks back and after a bit of research on similar problems, I found that my iTunes Library file had been corrupted during a boot. All you have to do is rebuild the iTunes Library file as per [Apple's instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-is/HT201561) and it should be working perfectly again.